# backups & deja dup not working

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I am running **Ubuntu 16.04** and used apt Backups to put it on my external-drive. This was another incremental backup.  Reinstalled from the same Ubuntu 16.04 64bit ISO dvd. I launched **backups**, and got error immediately, no choices . After trying backups, I installed **deja dup**.  It at least it let choose backup or restore and provide the location of the backup data [something like home/ken/DRV2/Docu*/Backups/studio]. However, Deja dup said error “Could not understand **Duplicity** version".  I found version of duplicity is 0.7.06 on my terminal. What can I do to get my data back?

Comment: I've never used `backups` so don't know what program it is sorry but as you mention `duplicity` I do see the 'updated' version is likely later than what you may have installed https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=duplicity so did you install 16.04.6 or an earlier ISO? and did you fully-upgrade before you attempted restore of data? This maybe less of an issue with `deja-dup` but I don't know what you used sorry (I use `rsync`)  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)

Comment: As far as I know what Ubuntu calls "backups" is the same as deja-dup, so I'm confused about your situation. When you run deja-dup, does it look like what you remember from Backups? Also, it is unlikely that your backup was stored in `/home` so that could be part of the confusion.  I'd like to help, but more information is needed. Please [edit] your question and include the exact location of your external drive (`/media/[user]/[whatever it is]`) and the exact error that you got "immediately, no choices" the first time you tried to restore.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to respond.  I did update 16.04.3, I find that backups uses duplicity. I moved the backup files to the internal disk. By the way my external drive is located /media/ken/DRV2. I generally screwed up. see my 2nd question.